# How to stop <select> option from resetting after clicking Go button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with maintaining the "selected" option from resetting to the first option. I tried e.preventDefault() but it didn't work out well for me because it won't allow me to generate data from other PHP code. So any suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Class Roster Generation</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "tbstyle.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#sbform").submit(function(event){
   loadAjax();
   event.preventDefault()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-6" style="background-color:#5BE848;">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                <center ><h4 class="label label-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>   Period</h4></center>
                <br>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="post" action="ftable.php" id="sbform">
                <span class="label label-info">Start Year</span>
                <span  value="2010" class="label label-default">2010</span> 
            <input type="hidden" name="perd" value="2010"  style="width:50px;"  >
                <select name="seasonT" class="">
                    <option value="1" >First Semester</option></p>
                    <option value="2">Second Semester</option>
                </select>
                    <select name="DepT"><?php include "try.php";?></select>         

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:12px;" type="submit" value="Go" name="Gobtn" id="Gobtn">
                </form>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include 'ftable.php'; ?>
    </div>


</body>
```

---

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have 2 options in my select element which is (First Sem and the Second Sem), if im going to choose Second sem and click the "Go/Submit" button  the selected option turned back into "First Sem" instead of "Second Sem" which i had selected last time

Comment: We don't know what `loadAjax()` does. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just saw that code from the web. so i tried but it only givesnothing to me. The real problem is every time I press the "Go button". The supposed to be "Selected" item in the select-option goes default.

Comment: Once you submit a form, it will load the whole page and send the data to server and the select tag will be reset it to first option. Are you trying to send data through ajax?

Comment: Nope. How can i prevent it from selecting the first option after sending the data..

Comment: Try adding `return false` at the end of your submit event listener

Comment: Store selected option in $_SESION variable, echo/re-create select dropdown html, with php, add 'selected' as attribute on last selected option?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
<select name="seasonT">
    <option value="1" <?= !empty($_POST) && $_POST['seasonT'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>First Semester</option></p>
    <option value="2" <?= !empty($_POST) && $_POST['seasonT'] == '2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Second Semester</option>
</select>
```

Whenever your form is submitted back to the same page, the code mentioned above makes the select option tag stay with the same selected option. I'm pretty sure this code works.

Comment: Notice: undefined index: seasonT -- that is all i got.

Comment: I've modified the code a little bit. Try the modified one and let me know if it works.

Comment: The same thing happened, undefined index.

Comment: May I know where in the page you get undefined index error?

Comment: at the line of $_POST['seasonT']

Comment: Make sure the name of the select tag is same as the index in $_POST. If you have it like `<select name="seasonT">...</select>`, then you need to use `$_POST['seasonT']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of function calls is wrong. First prevent default, then do everything else:

```
$("#sbform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   loadAjax();

});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of option into a variable before calling loadAjax and update the value of option after the call.

Let select with name="seasonT" have class="select_class", then the script will be like:

```
$("#sbform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var optionValue = $(".select_class").val();
    loadAjax();
    $(".select_class").val(optionValue).change();
});
```

Comment: where does "optionValue" comes from?

Comment: optionValue is the value that user has selected, let say optionValue=2 which refers to "Second Semester"